# Get Current Network Profile using c#

Tags: c#, powershell, networking, network-programming

I am trying to get my Network profile which works in Powershell returning my network name and what im after the NetworkCategory. (See Below)

```
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex   : 4
NetworkCategory  : Private
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

When in c# my GetNetworkProfile does not return anything.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript("Get-NetConnectionProfile");
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
            {
                if (outputItem != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Output line: [{outputItem}]");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm running Studio with elevated privileges.

I am aiming to be able to identify if the network category is public, and if it is then use Set-NetConnectionProfile to set it to Private within my application.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)`. Next, hover over `ps` and expand -> then expand `Streams` and then expand `Error`. Is there a count > 0 there? If so what does that error say? I can almost bet something like `Provider Load Failure`. If that's the case then you are running 32bit app on 64bit powershell, you can't do this. You can change your build `Platform Target` to `x64`, rebuild and try again. Let me know how this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a .NET Library where you find classes to get the needed information

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation?view=netcore-3.1

```html
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;

// Retrieve the ConnectionProfile.
ConnectionProfile internetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

// Pass the returned object to a function that accesses the connection data.
string connectionProfileInfo = GetConnectionProfileInfo(internetConnectionProfile);
```

Maybe this could help you?

Comment: This is a useful class but doesn't contain the NetworkCategory info

Answer (score 0):

You can get the network category from WMI:
root\StandardCimv2: select * from MSFT_NetConnectionProfile
NetworkCategory

0 for Public network

1 for Private network

2 for Domain network